# How to reverse the slope of a graphed line

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I'm trying to make a simple budget line graph that you would see in an economics class. But I need the slope of my line to be from 60 to 15 (inverse of what it is now).

I tried inversing the axis using numpy.flip() and plt.gca().invert_xaxis()

But I want to keep the x & y axis the same, just reverse the slope of the line so it shows from 60 too 15. I'm new to python and any help would be appreciated. I have included an image of my code below.

[image: My code]

Comment: Code should not be posted as text.

Comment: Why are you doing that over-complicated interpolation when you simply have a straight line from (1,1) to (15,58)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
plt.plot(x_[::-1], y)
```

The operation being done here reverses the order of the elements in the 'x_' array, resulting in the inverse of your slope.

Comment: THANK YOU. I made this post instead of starting from scratch because I was curious if there was an easy solution I couldn't find. Yeah I should've approached it differently from the start but I kept trying to make the original code I had work. Ended up with a hellacious combination of code from 3 packages.

Comment: That's the beauty of Python. There's almost always an easy way to do something. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you are plotting a line from (1,1) to (15,58). If you want to get the negative slope, you can simply swap the y values of the points.

```py
plt.plot([1, 15], [58,1])
```

Comment: OMG your right thank you I appreciate it I should've figured it out